# Screen Tearing on 17.10

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, nouveau, 17.10

I just upgraded to 17.10; I'm getting notably worse screen tearing on maximized Firefox.  I'm using nouveau drivers, and am hesitant to switch to nVidia due to [past issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919725/does-plymouth-still-run-without-quiet-splash).  How can I modify nouveau's settings on this?  Or is this a GNOME issue I can solve by trying, say, KDE?

```
$ lspci -k
...
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 OEM] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760 OEM]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

Answer (score 0):

Please switch to nvidia. They do work well in 17.10.
nouveau was very sluggish for me too.